# How do you enumerate MetaType's members?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net v2 (r480) and I have a `MetaType` class where some members have been added via the `Add()` method. I'd like to enumerate them (get a collection of `ValueMember` objects), but it seems that despite having a by-index indexer, `MetaType` is not an `IEnumerable`.

I have found two unsatisfactory ways of enumerating the members: reflection over a private field of `MetaType` which will break when the internal implementation is changed, and brute force attack which is slow, wasteful and plain silly.

Reflection:

```
ValueMember[] fields = ((IEnumerable)typeof(MetaType)
    .GetField("fields", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(metaType)).OfType<ValueMember>().ToArray();
```

Brute force (LINQ is used for brevity, a `for` loop would probably be faster):

```
ValueMember[] fields = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(i => metaType[i])
    .Where(m => m != null).ToArray();
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Yes, it isn't exposed. There is an internal `.Fields` property, but it would be worth adding a feature-request for exposing that on the public API.</s>

This is available from r581 onwards, by:

```
ValueMember[] fields = metaType.GetFields();
SubType[] subTypes = metaType.GetSubtypes();
```

Comment: I don't see a `Fields` property in r480 or in the latest sources, only a `fields` field. Also took your suggestion and opened [issue 313](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=313) for this feature request. In the sources I can see `//IEnumerable GetFields() { return fields; }` so it was a thought at one point. Why was it commented out?

Comment: Just after IsPrepared: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs